Error en id consecutivo en el registro de usuarios en Django
Tengo una aplicación web en django, que permite el registro de usuarios, pero ultimamente he notado que se salta la continuidad del ID.
ejemplo:



ID
USUARIO




1
Usuario1


2
Usuario2


4
Usuario3


7
Usuario4



y cuando realizo algunas consultas me sale error por que el id del usuario es mayor a la cantidad de usuarios registrados...
Como hago para mantener o forzar la continuidad en el registro?
Gracias Comunidad!!!

La teoría muy bien pero dónde esta el código?
